# CSS text alignment works differently between browsers?

Tags: html, css

How come a simple html button inner text appears centered in chrome but slightly shifted to the bottom right in Firefox when they have the same css properties ?

Chrome :

[image: 1]

Firefox :

[image: 2]

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id="button" type="button"><b>+</b></button>
<style>
    #button{
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 20px;
width: 25px;
border-width: 1px;
box-shadow: 0px  0px 5px grey;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 10;
position: absolute;
    }   
    
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“when they have the same css properties ?”_ - they don’t … there’s more applicable styles, than the few you explicitly set yourself. For starters, the padding applied to the button element _by the user agent stylesheet_ appears to be different in Chrome and Firefox … You might want to go look into a “css reset” stylesheet.

Comment: margin: 10; is not correct. you have to do margin: 10px;

Comment: and maybe you can inspect the element?

Answer (score 0):

You think all `css`rules are the same but it is not really the case.

For `css` rules you doesn't specify, browser takes default ones. And Chrome and Firefox doesn't choose the same defaults values.

In your particular example, for my side I have Firefox choosing `font-family: Tahoma` and Chrome choosing `font-family: Arial`.

As character widths are not the same between different font family you have the differences you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#button {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px grey;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You can use `lineheight` as same as height and width to align vertically